# Document.selecNodes(String e) returns a java.lang.VerifyError on android 1.6

Tags: xml, xpath, emulation

The following method takes in an XML file and an Xpath expression and returns the results as a string array. It was meant to run on an android device using API level 4 (Android 1.6). Problem is that I keep getting java.lang.VerifyError when it is run on the emulator.

Any ideas of what may be wrong?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private String[] evaluate(File file, String exp) {

    String[] values = null;

    try{

        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        //new line added because xpath not supported on oppaz android 1.6
        org.dom4j.Document doc = reader.read(file);
        java.util.List<Node> nl = null;

        try{
            //An error is always generated here java.lang.VerifyError
            nl = doc.selectNodes(exp);
        }
        catch(java.lang.VerifyError e){
            System.out.println("The following error occurred Mayne");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Object[] obj = nl.toArray();
        int j = obj.length;
        //Find out how many nodes were returned
        values =new String[j];

        for(int i=0;i<j;i++){

            Element  element = (Element) nl.get(i);                     
            NodeList nl2 = element.getChildNodes();
            String value = ((Node) nl2.item(0)).getNodeValue();

            values[i] = value;                  

        }


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return values;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. For those who are interested, here is how I solved it. Apart from dom4j, you need to have jaxen too for getting the XPath to work in android. Download [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/), add the jaxen*.jar to build path, and this should solve your problem. More info here [The Force Unleashed: XML+XPath On Android Using Dom4j And JaxeIn](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/the-force-unleashed-xmlxpath-on-android-using-dom4j-and-jaxen/). This is useful if you are planning to use XPath below 2.2. Android 2.2has inbuilt [XPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) capabilities